# split a cell with multiline data into separate rows per ID Pandas

Tags: pandas, split, python-3.5, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` with one column having multiline wrapped text:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1','3', '3'], \
                   'code_description': ['N1.12 - some description - further details of the case\nR31 - customer not satisfied,  (case processed)', '"C3.42 - some description - further details of the case\nL91.29 - some description : case processed"','"O20.12 - some description - further details of the case\nZ30.00 - some description / case further details\nL20 - some description  "'], \
                   'postcode': ['1037', '2512','2512'], \
                   'age': ['34', '56','56']})
```

I want to split the multiline data stored in `code_description` column and would like to obtain only codes such as N1.12 or R31 etc and only one code per row per `ID`. At the same time, I would like to keep the other columns in the dataframe but I am not getting how to get that.

I tried to use the str.split() method to split the line breaks and then use the same to separate the code. I did the following:

`df['code_description'].str.split("\n", expand=True).stack()`
and after that use
`df['code_description'].str.split(" - ").str[0]` 
to extract the codes. But with this method, I am loosing information related to `ID` and other columns such as `postcode` and `age`.

What I want as an output is the following:

```
   ID code_description  postcode  age
0   1            N1.12      1037   34
1   1              R31      1037   34
2   3            C3.42      2512   56
3   3           L91.29      2512   56
4   3           O20.12      2512   56
5   3           Z30.00      2512   56
6   3              L20      2512   56
```

Is there any nice way of obtaining such an output in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sr = df.code_description.str.extractall(
    re.compile('(?P<extracted_code_description>[0-9A-Z\.]+)\s-\s'))

sr = sr.set_index(sr.index.droplevel(1))

result = pd.merge(left=df, right=sr, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')

print(result[['ID', 'extracted_code_description', 'postcode', 'age']])
```

output:

```
  ID extracted_code_description postcode age
0  1                      N1.12     1037  34
0  1                        R31     1037  34
1  3                      C3.42     2512  56
1  3                     L91.29     2512  56
2  3                     O20.12     2512  56
2  3                     Z30.00     2512  56
2  3                        L20     2512  56
```

you may need to refine the regex in there, to be universally applicable to ALL of your cases.

Comment: Thank you. It works well for the small dataset. I still have to test it on the complete dataset.

Comment: that regex is really the key.